# if/else statement redirect not working

Tags: php

I have made this redirect depending on a condition.

I have a CMS, and I'm developing a mobile version of the site. The main CMS is linked to `site_url.com` while the mobile version is located on a subdomain `m.site_url.com`. Below function is an edited logout function in the mentioned CMS.

CodonModule is included as a php include in the `index.php` of the mobile site. This loads all of the CMS' functions basically.

Does the solution I've came up with allow such a redirect that I've done below, or do I require something else to find the subdomain, and based on that information, complete a redirect? At the moment, it will always redirect me to the else argument's link, regardless of where I trigger the script, whether on the subdomain, or the main domain. I'd like therefore to fix the script below, and for the condition to work.

`Auth::LogOut` triggers the logout process. I then add a redirect for the user to be redirected either to a desktop page (else argument) or mobile version (if they are on the subdomain).

When I did `$die(subdomain)` just below the `$subdomain` line, it would print out the name of the domain. Shouldn't it print out `m` instead for the subdomain, or have I made a mess of this code?

```
class Logout extends CodonModule 
{
    public function index()
    {

       $sub_domain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

       if($sub_domain == 'm')
       {
           Auth::LogOut();
           header('Location: http://m.site_url.com/index.php');
       }
       else
       {
           Auth::LogOut();
           header('Location: '.url('/'));
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `session_start();` at the top of the File right below `<?php` where u defined the `index()` function, If I'm Right the Sessions didn't even start (IDK), But Try to add it..

Maybe it will work..